# correct way to use $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

When I am using

```
$_SESSION['$name'] = '$name';
```

I am getting the desired result, but when I am using

```
$_SESSION['$name'] = 'name';
```

OR

```
$_SESSION['name'] = '$name';
```

I am not getting desired result!

Is this the right way in which I am getting the desired result???

Comment: It all depends on which is the desired result. You haven't said what the result is that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

**Thank you to OrangePill, as I didn't see the mistake.**

The answer is:

None of these are correct.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
```

You have created a variable `$name`.

You get the value of `$name` from *name* by using `'name'`.

eg

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
```

I have created the variable `$fname`.

```
<form>
 <input class="input" type="text"  name="fname" id="fname"  />
</form>
```

I get the value of `$fname` (in this case the user input for first name, as string), from the input field or element named `name="fname"`, which I need to format in php between `' '` as `'fname'`.

Comment: "You get the value if `$name` from _name_ by using `'name'`." - I have no idea what you're trying to say there, could you clarify?

Comment: Still hard to understand. The sentence I quoted doesn't make any sense. Your edit might be easier to understand if you actually added what you're talking about, i.e. an HTML form with an input field with the name attribute set to `fname` (I _think_ that's what you're talking about). The "it reads chars between `'`" is not really a good explanation either. If you want to explain that, talk about string literals, interpolation, and arrays in PHP, and how strings are used to index these arrays. But that'll probably be a waste of time since it's not clear at all what the OP isn't understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
```

In [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), variable interpolation (expanding variable to there values) does not occur in single quoted strings.

For example,

```
$name = 'user2534211';

echo '$name'; // will print $name

echo $name; // will print user2534211
echo "$name"; // will print user2534211;
```